# g++ (4.6.1) does not recognize -std=c++11

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

I'm trying to compiling a program (via Make) using g++ 4.6.1 with flag `-std=c++11`.
It's giving me:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
```

This is running on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty.
(the same program compiles smoothly on Mac OS)

Here's my g++:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.6.0-3~ppa1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 20110409 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.6.0-3~ppa1)
```

Comment: I bet that in 12.04 that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

Your program might be able to compile when compiled with the flag set to `-std=c++0x`, which was the other name for C++11 before the standard was released.